# Get the height of image of 100% width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the image height of its width of 100% from the browser's width.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var heightImage = $('ul.images img').height();
    $('ul.images').css("height", heightImage + "px");
});
```

The problem with the code above is when I resize the browser, and the height of images of 100% widths changes, the `heightImage` doesn't change.

So i decide to use:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var heightImage = $('ul.images img').height();
    $('ul.images').css("height", heightImage + "px");
});
```

There are two problem with the code above:

the image is in absolute position. Sometimes it display block, and sometime it display none. It catch the image height before the image fadein to show from the slideshow. It changes the height of the image when the browser size is changed. But if we resize the browser when the image is fading, while all images are display none, it will catch the height of image to be 0px.

and the second problem of that code is it only detects the height of the image when the browser size changes.

Can anyone please give me an alternative how to catch the height of images on slideshow with the width of 100% + on browser resize?

Thanks in advance.

**My HTML CODE**

```
<ul class="images">
   <li><img src="1.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="2.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="3.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

I just copy pasted this code from somewhere around here:

```
var triggers = $('ul.triggers li');
var images = $('ul.images li');
var lastElem = triggers.length-1;
var target;

triggers.first().addClass('active');
images.hide().first().show();

function sliderResponse(target) {
    images.fadeOut(500).eq(target).fadeIn(500);
    triggers.removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
}

triggers.click(function() {
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        target = $(this).index();
        sliderResponse(target);
        resetTiming();
    }
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    resetTiming();
});
$('.prev').click(function() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    lastElem = triggers.length-1;
    target === 0 ? target = lastElem : target = target-1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    resetTiming();
});

function sliderTiming() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
    sliderResponse(target);
}

var timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },5000);
function resetTiming() {
    clearInterval(timingRun);
    timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },5000);
}
```

Comment: What does "height of its width" mean?

Comment: the height of image when it's width is 100%.

Comment: Does [`outerHeight`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) not work?

Comment: What does outerHeight do actually? I have not tried it, but I am sure the result will be the same?

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
var heightImage = $('ul.images img').height();
$(window).resize(function(){
    heightImage = $('ul.images img').height();
    $('ul.images').css("height", heightImage + "px");
}).resize();
```

Comment: Thanks man. But, if we resize the browser when the image is fading, while all images are display none, it will catch the height of image to be 0px

Comment: So, the scenario is there are three images in `ul.images` Each images will display 5 seconds one after another (what we call it as slideshow). If the browser is resized when the next image is going to show up, it will catch the height of image to be 0px because actually there are no images to display at that time. But if we resize the browser before the images is fadeout, it will catch the real height of the images.

Comment: hmmm, it's pretty difficult for you. just a suggestion: on resize stop the animation and and show the image and get the image height. good luck.

Comment: can you please help me to do that with my code above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED 2:**

one simple way is to write the whole thing inside a function and call it in a loop if the height is 0.

```
function setHeight(){
    var imageHeight=$('ul.images img').height();
    if(imageHeight==0){
        clearTimeout(window.TO);
        window.TO=setTimeout(setHeight(),100);
    }
    else{
        $('ul.images').css("height", imageHeight + "px");
    }
}
setHeight()
$(window).resize(function(){
    setHeight()
});
```

Comment: I vote it up. But when I tried it it doesn't do anything at all, it doesn't catch the height of the image, and in the console there is no error message about it. What's wrong?

Comment: I am sorry, I type it wrong. It works. But it makes the browser load so slow when I resize the window. Is it something about the loop?

Comment: And in the console log there is a message "too much recursion"?

Comment: yes it is, I'm working on it, just wait a few minutes

Comment: can you please post your whole html code in order to make it easier to resemble?

Comment: the **EDIT 2** is a way to reduce the number of recursions, it will call the `setHeight()` function every 100 milliseconds.

Comment: it's still like that. sometime it doesn't change the height. Is there any other way to achieve this, please?

Comment: can I ask where do you use the script? is it inside the `sliderResponse()` function?

Comment: no, it is separated away from there. is it a problem too?

Comment: so please tell me where do you use it :)